# Compare 2 versions of a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, diff

How to compare 2 versions of a compiled .NET assembly to see changes between the 2 versions? I have a library not well-documented and I need to know what has been changed between the old version and the new version.

Comment: Do you have the source code? Is this source code version controller? It's always easier to work with source code rather than compiled assemblies.

Comment: No I don't have source code, it seems NDepend will make the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) offers many features to handle .NET code diff. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the tool*.

The panel **Search by Change** is dedicated to browse assemblies code diff. Notice that:

- You can plug to NDepend any code diff tool used by the menu *Compare older and newer version of source file*
- If you don't have the source code, only the raw assemblies, there is the option *Compare older and newer version disassembled with Reflector*

[image: NDepend Search by Diff Panel]

Notice also in the screenshot that a [CQLinq code query](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) is generated to browse the diff.

```
from m in Application.Methods 
where m.CodeWasChanged() 
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

Many others default diff queries and rules are proposed by default, that will let you browse .NET code diff in a smart way.

- [Types that used to be 100% covered but not anymore](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_that_used_to_be_100__covered_but_not_anymore.html)
- [API Breaking Changes: Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Methods.html)
- [Avoid making complex methods even more complex](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_%28Source_CC%29.html)
- [Avoid decreasing code coverage by tests of types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_decreasing_code_coverage_by_tests_of_types.html)
- [From now, all types added or refactored should respect basic quality principles](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_From_now,_all_types_added_or_refactored_should_respect_basic_quality_principles.html)
- [Avoid transforming an immutable type into a mutable one](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_transforming_an_immutable_type_into_a_mutable_one.html)
- [Heuristic to find types moved from one namespace or assembly to another](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Heuristic_to_find_types_moved_from_one_namespace_or_assembly_to_another.html)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Reflector, you can use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com) to perform this task. Please note that this is a commercial software, but the site offers a free trial. Here's an [online tutorial](http://s3.amazonaws.com/NDependOnlineDemos/BuildComparison_viewlet_swf.html) on how one can use NDepend to compare two assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Red Gate's .NET reflector`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and you'll be able to take a look at the actual code changes between the assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

I use reflector, with the Diff plugin.

You might also find this Hanselman post useful, as it reviews other tools, including Reflector Diff.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingChangeWithNETAssemblyDiffTools.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the code or just the assemblies? In case you have the compiled versions, one way is to dig into them using the object browser in visual Studio. The other approach might be using disassembler like [Red Gates Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) to see to the source code.